# Algorithm to divide a set of symbols with constraints into minimum number of subsets

Tags: algorithms, combinations

I have a set 
$$
  S=\{a,c,d,e,f,j,m,q,s,t\}
$$
with a constraint 
$$
  C=\{am,cm,de,df,dm,ds,ef,em,eq,es,et,fj,fm,fs,jm,js\}
$$ 
where $xy$ in $C$ means that $x$ and $y$ cannot be in the same subset. I would like an algorithm to split set $S$ into subsets $S_j$ such that:

1. The number of $S_j$ is minimized
2. The difference between size of each subset is as large as possible.

For example in this case, both of the following satisfy (1), but the first is optimal:
$$
  \{\{q,a,c,d,j,t\},\{m,s\},\{f\},\{e\}\} \\
  \{\{a,c,e,j\},\{m,s,q,t\},\{d\},\{f\}\}
$$

Coming from a computer science background, I wonder whether Mathematicians have devised an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: What does the second constraint mean? "The difference between each subset is as large as possible"? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry to be so vague. It means the size of each subset.@5xum

Comment: Expand more on the two constraints. Which constraint has precedence (do we care about (1) or (2) more)? Also, how are we calculating the "difference between size of each subset"? Do we take the sum of the differences of the sizes of each pair of subsets? Do we take the difference of the sizes of the largest and the smallest subset?

Comment: Actually, there may be many alternatives when computing Sj one by one. I want to choose the longest one from them.@mapierce271